# Yii2: Do DefaultValueValidator or FilterValidator influence other validation rules?

Tags: validation, yii2

Both validators are no real validators, rather they can change an attribute value. If such pseudo validators are used in model rules, do they have any effect on other real validators?

For example, when a default and a required validator are used for the same attribute, will the required validator never fail?

Or are there any precedences with such validators? Or is the order of the validation rules crucial?

Answer (score 0):

The `pseudo` validators alter the values of attributes. Thus any subsequent validators on the same attributes will validate against the altered values.
The order *is* crucial. The validators are created from `rules()` using [\yii\base\Model::createValidators()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Model.php#L415) in the order they appear in `rules()`.

For your specific example, when the `required` rule is first, validating against it will return `false`. However, when the `default` rule is first, the attribute already has a set value thus the validation for `required` will return `true`.